# Best way to end a function that contains an array in AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, function

So I'm real new to AS3 and I'm trying to figure out a solution to end a function I created for a matching game. I want to have the function end when all the cards are used up in the array. What is the easiest way to go about this?

```
private var games:Object = {
            easy:{
                    tiledeck:[1,1,2,2] 
                    ,xOffset:450   
                    ,yOffset:320    
                    ,incrementX:200 
                    ,incrementY:200 
                    ,columns:2      
                    ,rows:2         
                }
            ,hard:{
                    tiledeck:[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]
                    ,xOffset:235
                    ,yOffset:320
                    ,incrementX:200
                    ,incrementY:200
                    ,columns:4
                    ,rows:2
                }
    };

    public function KT(game:String){
        buttonMode = true
        var gameConfig = games[game];
        var tiledeck:Array = gameConfig.tiledeck.concat();
        for (var x=1; x<=gameConfig.columns; x++){
            for (var y=1; y<=gameConfig.rows; y++){
                var random_card = Math.floor(Math.random() * tiledeck.length);
                var tile:animalTile = new animalTile(); 
                tile.animal = tiledeck[random_card];
                tiledeck.splice(random_card,1);
                tile.gotoAndStop(5);
                tile.x = (x - 1) * gameConfig.incrementX + gameConfig.xOffset;
                tile.y = (y - 1) * gameConfig.incrementY + gameConfig.yOffset;
                tile.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,tile_clicked);
                addChild(tile);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "all the cards are used up in the array"? do you mean when distribution is over? Since I don't know what kind of card game you are making it is a bit hard for me to help you

Comment: Well, doesn't it end already? Your for loop is the last statement in your function.... Otherwise you can always end a function with *return;*.

Comment: It is a matching card game. The user selects two cards to match and the array holds the cards for matching. I have a back button set up in the main timeline to go back to the start screen when selected. The problem I am having is that if the user hits the go back button before the function is done, the tiles still remain on the screen in the start menu. So I need to kill the function whenever this button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not what you think it is.

The array is properly discarded from memory.

However, you used `addChild(tile)`. This means you'll also have to `removeChild(tile)`. Personally, I recommend adding a `DisplayObjectContainer` that you add the cards to. Kinda like a plastic sheet to put the cards on. Then, when the user presses the back button, you remove the plastic sheet... and all the cards come with it.

You haven't provided the code for the back button though, so I can't help you with integrating this functionality. My advice: Make some sort of game object responsible for cleanup, so all the button has to do is `game.exitGame();` and then whatever code you use to go back right now.